# Jquery Append Data And Then Auto Click

Tags: jquery

I write this code on document ready, not working.

```
$('body').append('<a id="lnkHidden" href="http://www.google.com.tr" target="_blank">Go To Google</a>');
$('#lnkHidden').trigger('click');
```

Yeah, link appended. But not click generated link after.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You can't no more on modern browsers force a popup to open without any user interaction

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').append('<a id="lnkHidden" href="http://www.google.com.tr" target="_blank">Go To Google</a>');
$("#lnkHidden").get(0).click();
});
```

Comment: Be aware about popup blocker as target blank is specified on anchor

Comment: I tried but blocked by **Google Chrome Popup Blocker**

Comment: @GürayYarar Fortunately, you can no more do that... You could bind it to document click event though, meaning this kind of behaviour needs some user interaction, e.g:   http://jsfiddle.net/p3pov5jh/

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
$('body').append('<a id="lnkHidden" href="http://www.google.com.tr" target="_blank">Go To Google</a>');

$('#lnkHidden').click(function(){
    location.href = this.href;
}).trigger('click');
```